# I am facing this issue from very long time the problem is when I dynamically create list with custom widget

Tags: flutter

I am facing this issue for a very long time the problem is when I dynamically create a list with a custom widget and when I remove any item from that list it only removes the last item, not that particular one

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_tailor_shop/util/color_class.dart';
import 'package:my_tailor_shop/util/common_class.dart';
import 'package:my_tailor_shop/widgets/common_measurement_widget.dart';

class MeasurementsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onValueChangedCallback,onRowDeleteCallback;

  const MeasurementsWidget({Key? key, required this.onValueChangedCallback, required this.onRowDeleteCallback})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MeasurementsWidget> createState() => _MeasurementsWidgetState();
}

class _MeasurementsWidgetState extends State<MeasurementsWidget> {
  final ColorClass _colorClass = ColorClass();
  List<CommonMeasurementWidget> list= [];
  final List _listToSearch = [
    {'name': 'Amir', 'id': 12},
    {'name': 'Raza', 'id': 11},
    {'name': 'Praksh', 'id': 10},
    {'name': 'Nikhil', 'id': 9},
    {'name': 'Sandeep', 'id': 8},
    {'name': 'Tazeem', 'id': 7},
    {'name': 'Najaf', 'id': 6},
    {'name': 'Izhar', 'id': 5},
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 2),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: Text("Add Measurements",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: _colorClass.colorBlack,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontFamily: CommonClass.robotoBold))),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
            add();

                  // widget.onValueChangedCallback(0, "",_list.length);
                },
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    color: _colorClass.colorDarkOrange,
                  ),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: _colorClass.colorWhite,
                    size: 15,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          ListView(
            shrinkWrap:true,children: [

            ...list,
      
          ],)

        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onDeleteWidgetFromTree (index) {
  setState(() {
  list.remove(index);
  });
  // widget.onRowDeleteCallback(0);

  }
  void onValueChangedCallback(header, value,index) {


    // widget.onValueChangedCallback(header, value,0);
  }

  void add() {

    setState(() {
      list.add( CommonMeasurementWidget(
          _listToSearch,
          onValueChangedCallback,
          onDeleteWidgetFromTree));
    });
  }
}
class CommonMeasurementWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List listToSearch;
  final Function  onDeleteWidgetFromTree;
  final Function  onValueChangedCallback;

  CommonMeasurementWidget(
      this.listToSearch,
      this.onValueChangedCallback,
      this.onDeleteWidgetFromTree, {
        Key? key,
      }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CommonMeasurementWidget> createState() => _CommonMeasurementWidgetState();
}

class _CommonMeasurementWidgetState extends State<CommonMeasurementWidget> {
  // @override
  final ColorClass _colorClass = ColorClass();

  int _selectedId = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: _colorClass.colorBlack),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: _colorClass.colorOrangeTransparent),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: [

          Text(
              'Hashcode: ${this.hashCode.toString()}'),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                widget.onDeleteWidgetFromTree(widget);

              });
            },
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: const Icon(Icons.close),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),

          DropdownButton<int>(
            value: _selectedId, //selected
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
            iconSize: 24,
            elevation: 16,
            style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
            underline: Container(
              height: 2,
              color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
            ),
            onChanged: (int? newValue) {
setState(() {
  _selectedId=newValue!;
});
            },
            items: <int>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                .map<DropdownMenuItem<int>>((int value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value.toString()),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),

          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Full Name',
                ),
                onChanged: (text) {
                  setState(() {

                    //you can access nameController in its scope to get
                    // the value of text entered as shown below
                    //fullName = nameController.text;
                  });
                },
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screen recording for better understanding https://github.com/AkshayScott/image/blob/main/screen_recording.gif

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `UniqueKey` in your `add` method:

```
void add() {

    setState(() {
      list.add( CommonMeasurementWidget(
          _listToSearch,
          onValueChangedCallback,
          onDeleteWidgetFromTree,
          key: UniqueKey(),));
    });
  }
```

See https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working like a charm